# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Hte inconnu

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony

A friend give me his project and I wanna execute it in my laptop,

So after installing all dependencies, I had to configure the DB but I get errors when I run this command

```
bin/console doctrine:database:create


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H▒te inconnu.

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H▒te inconnu.

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H▒te inconnu.

  [PDOException]
  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H▒te inconnu.
```

if someOne can explain what means this error please?

My config script:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
    

    default:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     '%database_host%'
        port:     '%database_port%'
        dbname:   '%database_name%'
        user:     '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset:  UTF8
        logging:  true
```

THe content of parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_host: mysql
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    database_version: 5.7
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: project_mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.11
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - "./.docker-volumes/sqldb:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./docker/mysql:/home"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3307:3306"
```

Comment: What is the contents of your env file?

Comment: I'm using symfony 3.3 and I can't find .env files

Comment: Could you then share the contents of your Parameters.yml file? And do you run your project with docker or just locally on your machine?

Comment: I edited my question and project is running with docker

Comment: Oke awesome, i think it would also be handy to share your docker(-compose) configuration. Did you also try to set database_password to 'root'?

Comment: Finally,I could create my db (the problem was host I had to create one with "mysql" name)

Comment: Well done, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that with your current configuration your project cannot make a proper connection to your database. This could be caused by misconfiguring your `host`, missing a password - or when using docker - connecting to the wrong container or not finding it at all.

I used this configuration in my Symfony 3 project:

parameters.yml

```yaml
    database_host: db (name of the docker container configured in docker-compose.yml)
    database_port: null
    database_name: docker_db (name of the database configured in docker-compose.yml)
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
```

Docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: docker_db
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the value of `DATABASE_URL` in my .env file, the connection to my database